# Flask Simple Question About Printing Strings with newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

For Example, I am using the following code.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form['test']
        print(test)
        print('\nprinted')
```

If I send the post request with a value containing newline '\n' the print method will not print the content with the new line but printing directly like this  "print('\nprinted')" will print the content with a new line.

Example: Sending data.

Request:

```
curl  http://127.0.0.1:9090/test -XPOST -d "test=\nhello"
```

Response:

```
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:9090
Press CTRL+C to quit
\nhello

printed
```

Is there any way to pass the data containing the newline and the result containing the actual newline?

Updated:

```
test = request.form['test']
print(test)
```

The desired output should look like this for the above code.

Input:
`curl -XPOST -d 'test=\nhello' http://127.0.0.1:5000`

Output:

```
hello
```

The hello should be printed after a newline.

Comment: ``
test = request.form['test']
        print(test)
``
The desired output should look like this for the above code.

Input:  curl -XPOST -d 'test=\nhello' http://127.0.0.1:5000 

Output:

hello 

The hello should be printed after a newline.

Comment: I have added it to my question.I hope you did understand now.

Comment: None of your solutions worked. It really does not make more sense to use -w "\n". 
I only showed the example of passing data via curl. What will you do if it is passed through a web page? The newline should actually show in the flask response not in curl.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's due to the way the input field value is handled. So it escapes the escape character, because it wants to keep the format of the input as exact as possible.

So the true values of your varaible is `test = \\nhello`

You can fix this like so:

```
test.replace("\\n", "\n") # "\\nhello" -> "\nhello"
```

Here we replace two escape characters with a single one

Comment: The actual output should be printed with a newline if I passed data with "\n".
Would you again read my question?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the question if it is not what I've answered. The desired output variable should look like `"\nhello"` and print the an empty line continued by "hello". If this is the case, then the code above should take care of that

Comment: The question is about printing the data with the newline that is passed via the POST request.

Comment: Yes, so the two print statements you have in the question do not contain a variable equal to eachother. The variable test is equal to `\\nhello` and in the latter print statement it's `\nPrinted`. So the problem lies in the fact that your varaible from the POST request has been encoded, and to keep the variable exactly as the input, it escapes escape characters. So the test variables value needs to be changed from `\\nhello` -> `\nhello`. And the above code should take care of that

Comment: I understood and tried it but it does not seem working. Did you verify it from your side?

Comment: I do not know how effective this method is but I just solved it like this. counter = test.count("\\n") test = counter * "\n" + test print(test)

Comment: @kho I've updated my answer, which should do the job.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the answer to the question, so other who stumble upon it sees it fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for now.

```
counter = test.count("\\n") 
test = counter * "\n" + test 
print(test)
```